# Phrozen ABS-like resin profile (.cfg File) for Chitubox, where to download it?

Tags: resin

I am a beginner at 3D printing. I use:

- Phrozen Sonic Mini 4K
- Chitubox

In Chitubox, there are some resin profiles preloaded and selectable. There also is the possibility to import profiles (.cfg file format).

However, I don't seem to be able to find a .cfg profile file for the Phrozen ABS-like resin so that I could import it in Chitubox.

Am I misunderstanding some concept here? Why can I not find a .cfg-file for the ABS-like resin?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Chitubox install?

Comment: You can export settings - someone might need to make a profile available somewherer